# Fine State Automata for an expression

Tags: regex, finite-automata, state-machine

I have three expressions, and I am trying to draw an FSA for them, and want to know if I have tackled it correctly. I have included the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use visualizers like [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) or [jex](https://jex.im). They are pretty simple and usefull.

For example.
`(?:[+][0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{8})|(?:[+][0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{6})|(?:[+][0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{6})`
provides this:
[image: picture from debuggex]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
[+]([0-9]{2}\s([0-9]{2}\s)*([0-9]{8}|[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{6})|[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{6})
```

[image]

[Online Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/46oLGq4q3ASiPIoN)